# Should aws lambda return something?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS Lambda and Lambda Edge and I'm trying to understand the purpose. In Lambda Edge I see in the promo page it kind of implies Edge is a middleware in that you can modify the request.

I see in the nodejs examples that to continue processing of a request you can use `callback(null, request);` but whenever I use that I get a 502 response.

For example can I add/modify a header and then continue a request to a Cloudformation or API Gateway backend or must the lambda return an object of some sort?

Here is an example (logs show header is added and all is well, just that curl returns 502):

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    console.log(context);
    console.log(event);

    const request = event;

    request.headers.bar = 'foo';

    console.log(event);

    callback(null, request);
};
```

Comment: `request` here is a reference to `event.Records[0].cf.request` with any modifications to the request object that you have made, subject to certain restrictions. This allows request processing to continue, with a modified request, but is rejected if your object is not valid or if you've tried to manipulate it improperly.  Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of something you're trying that is failing with a 502.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot added code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues that sometimes stumps people when trying to use Lambda@Edge is that testing your script successfully in the Lambda console only tests whether your code can run without throwing exceptions.

What it doesn't test for is whether your test event looks like a test event that CloudFront would generate, or whether your returned values would actually be interpreted as valid by CloudFront.

The `event` you are passed is a complex object containing one record, and inside there is `cf` (CloudFront) which contains `request`.  If you are a response trigger, it also contains `response`.

See [Lambda@Edge Event Structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html).  There are test event templates in the Lambda console for various types of CloudFront interactions.

So you need to get the original event's request from the right part of the structure:

```
const request = event; // incorrect
const request = event.Records[0].cf.request; // correct
```

Headers are confusing at first, but this is actually an example of very sensible engineering design.  HTTP headers are not case sensitive in HTTP/1.x and are always lowercase in http/2, but JavaScript object keys are always case sensitive... so a sensible representation of headers takes all of these factors into account, as well as the fact that some headers can appear more than once and the ordering can be relevant.

In `headers`, the object key is always lowercase, and each value is an array of objects that contains a `key` (which must match the outer key, except for lettercase) and a `value` (the header).

```
request.headers.bar = 'foo'; // incorrect
request.headers['bar'] = [ { key: 'Bar', value: 'foo' } ]; // correct
```

Additionally, certain headers are blacklisted -- for reasons of security or simple sanity, you can't add or manipulate them.

See [Headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-requirements-limits.html#lambda-header-restrictions) in the Lambda@Edge section of the CloudFront Developer Guide.

Also, remember that CloudFront is a cache, and caches have cache keys -- the unique value that identifies a specific request, so that other, identical requests can be determined to actually be identical and served with the same response.  The cache key in CloudFront consists of only what CloudFront is configured to send to the origin -- which does not include headers that you haven't whitelisted for forwarding to the origin in the Cache Behavior settings.  Trying to set or modify a header inappropriately will result in a 502 error.  In the example above, you would need to whitelist the `Bar` header for forwarding to the origin, in the cache distribution settings.

You might find it initially easier to learn by trying to modify a response, rather than a request, because they are somewhat more forgiving.

Note that in request triggers, you have essentially four possible outcomes:

- leave the request unmodified and return control to CloudFront by using `return callback(null, request);` without changing anything
- modify the request by modifying the request object and then `return callback(null, request);
- stop further CloudFront processing, and generate a response directly by building a valid response object and calling `return callback(null, response);`
- throw a hard exception by setting the first `callback()` response to something other than null

In a viewer request trigger, generating a response returns the response to the viewer without checking the cache and without caching the response.

An origin request trigger only fires after the cache has already been checked, and the object is not there.  If you generate a response in an origin request trigger, the response is stored in the cache and returned to the requester.  The request is never sent to the origin if you generate a response in this trigger.  If you modify the request, it is sent to the origin and the response is cached unless configured not to be cached.

An origin response trigger modifies or replaces the response from the origin, and the modified response is stored on the cache.

A viewer response trigger modifies or replaces the response that was either fetched from the cache or from the origin.  The modified response is not cached.

Response triggers are also able to inspect the original request, in cases where this might be desirable.

Comment: Thanks. I guess if different triggers have different behaviour this is where I have been falling down. I've mainly been testing with API Gateway triggers where in fact I think I need a CloudFront trigger so it continues the request?